# MS Excel - if cell contain exact words, do multiplication

Tags: excel

i am doing an excel where i have this issue and i dont know how to write the code.

If there is an exact wording of YES in a cell A1. How do i write the formula in such a way that if Cell A1 has Yes, multiply the (multiplication of Cell B1 & Cell C1) by 7%? for CELL D1

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really just try something here. You have the logic down, now just try to do some research. Start with a function called `IF()`.

Comment: Try `=IF(A1="Yes",(B1*C1)*7%,"")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below format.

=IF(A1="YES",B1*C1,)

Firstly, Checking A1 is "YES" or other one. And then, if A1 is "YES" --> multiply B1 and C1.

I think you get a concept and try to apply the formula which you want.